# MS Office Mobile Service (OMS) for Outlook connection error

Tags: outlook, sms, ms-office, sms-gateway

I developed an OMS web service by following guidelines at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606754.aspx.

Whenever I tried to configure the SMS account in Outlook I get following error.

"Outlook did not receive a response from the Web service because of a problem connecting to the server. try again later."

Although it does create the account, and whenever I try to send sms the same error occurs but I receive the sms as well. That means outlook can send the message to my web service but why it is giving error?

Searched a lot on this topic but no one seems to have a solution.

Greatly appreciate if someone could help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you help me in creating a similar Web Service, because i am trying to make a service following the same help, but when i put the URL in Outlook it just says that the Web Service URL is corrupted. I even tried to publish it on our local server, but still the same error of corrupted url.

Comment: Atlast i found the problem. It was just https was required instead of http

Comment: Sure leave a message here or email me : jawaid at ibexoft dot com

Answer (score 0):

You should check how to send SMS from Outlook Mobile Service (Outlook 2007) with Ozeki NG SMS Gateway:
http://sms-integration.com/p_83-outlook-mobile-service-sms.html

I hope it helps. The support team is also very responsive.

BR